# build failed - unable to get mutable windows environment variables

Tags: android, node.js, npm, react-native

I'm trying to run a react-native version **0.59.5** project but when i run **react-native run-android** command i get this error. I tried changing **node** and **npm** versions but it didn't help. what is it related to? i don't understand where it comes from.

**build failed -> unable to get mutable windows environment variables**

[image: error]

Comment: Make sure to have your ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES set and declared on your machine. Says how to do it in the React setup tutorial.

Comment: @AleksandarZoric i've checked all of them, there is no problem.

Comment: @Gray, did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

buddy recently I have face the same problem and I fix by figuring out what to do. First of all the jdk path through Edit System Environment Variable should be set correctly.
Edit System Environment Variable

Open System Properties
**Click** -> Environment Variable

Click -> New... -> Set Variable name to "**JAVA_HOME**"(without quotation""),and set Variable value {after installing jdk-12} to

> `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12`

Now **click OK**

At the 2nd step Go to System variable and click on "Path" then click New and paste `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12`

**click OK**

[*Please set the JDK path carefully*. Note: I was `install jdk 12` after trying other jdk versions,but JDK 12 work smoothly...idk why:)]

After that, if you are using flutter in android. You must click on gradlew to open terminal.
In the terminal just write **`gradlew signingReport`**

After doing all these steps you will get your **SHA-1 & SHA-256** key for the firebase connection.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same isuue
I change android/gradle **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'** to **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'** and also change android/gradle/wrapper/grale-wrapper.prperties **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip** to **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).